# System is not booting up when mixing 1600 RAM kit with 1333

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a X8DA3/X8DAI motherboard
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DA3.cfm

, 2x e5645 2.4Ghz, and 32GB 1333, dual channel memory 4x8GB RAM sticks,
just got Kingston Hyperx Savage 16GB kit (2x8) but 1600 by mistake,
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00N9PVZXO/ref=twister_B00OR0E500?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N9PVZXO)

It should have been 1333. I tried to add them in to test, but the system is not booting up.

This is how the sticks should go.

[image]

And this is the motherboard map.

[image]

I tried to mix and match but no go. 
If I just use the Savage sticks, or only my old Hynix ones, the system boots up, but soon as I mix them no go.

http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/5500/MNL-1031.pdf

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried setting the 1600/timings RAM to 1333/timings in the BIOS?

Comment: No , I did not touch the BIOS at all. Thing is I cant boot with 1600 sticks mix so bios wont show me anything if I use my old ones. Or ?

Comment: Put 1600 in first, go to bios change speed to 1333, then add 1333 after.

Comment: Do what @Carl B said and then report back if it worked.